# I can't use getRef in onBingViewHolder method, I'm trying to show selected item in another view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to show the selected items in another view and I can't get the key using getRef method. How should I get the key to pass the data? I tried to find similar solutions on StackOverflow but just can't find it...

This is my onBindViewHolder:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    final String productKey = getRef(position).getKey();

    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    //Picasso.with(mContext).load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap().load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
      
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SingleProductActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("ProductKey", productKey);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And my class where I'm trying to show upload data.

```
String productKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("ProductKey");
    mDatabaseRef.child(productKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()){
                String productName = snapshot.child("mName").getValue().toString();
                String productDesc = snapshot.child("mDescription").getValue().toString();
                String imageUrl = snapshot.child("mImageUrl").getValue().toString();

                productDescriptionTxt.setText(productDesc);
                singleProductNameTxt.setText(productName);
                productPriceTagTxt.setText("100");
                Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap().load(imageUrl).into(singleProductImg);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my whole adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
private String link;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;


public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mUploads = uploads;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    final String productKey = getRef(position).getKey();

    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    //Picasso.with(mContext).load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap().load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SingleProductActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("ProductKey", productKey);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private CardView parent;
    private View v;

    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productNameTxt);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImg);
        //v označava jedan prikazan item
        v = itemView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the `getRef(position).getKey();` output returned?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getRef' in 'ImageAdapter'. I cant use that method

Comment: What is the type of your adapter? Please edit your question and add the entire content of your adapter class. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I added whole adapter @AlexMamo

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your ImageAdapter class extends [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter). That being said, you are getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'getRef' in 'ImageAdapter'.

Because the RecyclerView.Adapter class doesn't contain any getRef() method inside it, hence the error. However, [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/980d0cc8e0f319fece43c23716ec126858936fea/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) does. As you can see, the  [getRef()](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/980d0cc8e0f319fece43c23716ec126858936fea/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L113) method is present in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter class and **not** in the RecyclerView.Adapter class.

To solve this, you either adapt to the code of the [Firebase-UI](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/) library, or you keep using the RecyclerView.Adapter and get the "productKey" like so:

```
Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
String productKey = uploadCurrent.getProductKey();
```

But this will only work if you have the `productKey` as a field inside the `Upload` class. If you don't have it yet, add it and populate it when you add data to the database.